# compile time required function parameter checking

Tags: javascript

Is there a best practice way of enforcing parameters in functions at build time vs runtime?  For example if i have following function:

```
    function localize(strings, key, ...args) {

        return ...
    }
```

and I called it as such:

```
    var result = localize('myKey')
```

I did not pass the first parameter ('strings').  I would like to throw a compile error and not wait until runtime to get the error.

Comment: What do you mean? Javascript is not a compiled language, so there is no 'build time' at which errors could possibly be caught. Unless you are using something like Typescript, etc.?

Comment: You're right obviously, bad wording.  I'm building a react app with es6.  Is there a way to force the correct number of parameters are passed to a function before catching it at runtime?  If the answer is no, it's not possible because it's not compiled i accept that.  I just want to make sure there isn't some good way of doing this i'm unaware of.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Javascript is not compiled, and dynamically typed, there is no way to enforce the contract in your example except at runtime.

However, you can use a build system like Typescript, Flow, etc, to add type annotations to your code. These require a compilation step BUT the issue you have in your example would be caught by both during that step.

Without that, there is no way to get what you want as far as I know. The best you could do in vanilla javascript is to validate the arguments you are given inside the `localize` function, and use logs/errors so that you can easily identify the issue when you test your code locally. The important bit here is that without actually running your code, there is no way to catch the error in your example using vanilla JS.